# getOptionChain() not returning Index Options Data in R

Tags: r, quantmod

I am trying to call all the `^SPX` options tables via `quantmod`:

```
library("quantmod")

# Returns the front month
getOptionChain("^SPX")

# does not return all the Option Tables
getOptionChain("^SPX", Exp=NULL)
```

The error message I get:

```
> getOptionChain("^SPX", NULL)
Error in (function (object = nm, nm)  : 
  attempt to set an attribute on NULL
```

How do I fix this issue so i can call all option tables?

Comment: Upgrade to the latest quantmod on CRAN.

Comment: `> sessionInfo("quantmod")
R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
character(0)

other attached packages:
[1] quantmod_0.4-5`  @JoshuaUlrich I think I am up to date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last two expiration dates for `"^SPX"` do not have data for calls and puts, respectively. Here's a patch you can apply to fix the issue (and an issue with commas in numeric data, which causes them to be kept as character):

```
diff --git a/R/getOptionChain.R b/R/getOptionChain.R
index fb490ef..b3cca51 100644
--- a/R/getOptionChain.R
+++ b/R/getOptionChain.R
@@ -20,13 +20,17 @@ getOptionChain.yahoo <- function(Symbols, Exp, ...)
       XML::xmlValue(x)
     }
   }
-  NewToOld <- function(x) {
+  NewToOld <- function(x, nm) {
+    if(is.null(x))
+      return(x)
     # clean up colnames, in case there's weirdness in the HTML
-    x <- setNames(x, make.names(names(x)))
+    x <- setNames(x, make.names(nm))
     # set cleaned up colnames to current output colnames
     d <- with(x, data.frame(Strike=strike, Last=last, Chg=change,
       Bid=bid, Ask=ask, Vol=volume, OI=openinterest,
       row.names=`contractname`, stringsAsFactors=FALSE))
+    # remove commas from the numeric data
+    d[] <- lapply(d, gsub, pattern=",", replacement="", fixed=TRUE)
     d[] <- lapply(d, type.convert, as.is=TRUE)
     d
   }
@@ -100,8 +104,7 @@ getOptionChain.yahoo <- function(Symbols, Exp, ...)
   dftables <- XML::xmlApply(XML::getNodeSet(tbl, xpaths$tables), XML::readHTMLTable, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
   names(dftables) <- table.names

-  dftables <- mapply(setNames, dftables, table.headers, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
-  dftables <- lapply(dftables, NewToOld)
+  dftables <- mapply(NewToOld, x=dftables, nm=table.headers, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
   dftables
 }
```

Comment: I just [pushed this to the development version on GitHub](https://github.com/joshuaulrich/quantmod/commit/77ac0949cd6ce941b35f8571fca84483ab5b9216). It will be in the next release to CRAN.